# Use of HTTPS express,js server and user/password pair

Tags: authentication, https, express

I am writing an HTTPS web server using express.js. It does not have super secure, I think ssl certificates is overkill and not a good option for client apps. I have routes for my restAPI. There will be a login page. So I will have a user/password pair available to me.

Can I use this information alone to allow access to my HTTPS routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking whether [basic auth](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) over https is secure. The answer is yes, that's a reasonable security architecture, and is widely used for authenticating [APIs](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/api_authentication_and_how_it_got_that_way_from_http_basic_to_oauth_2.0). It's fine to route based on the basicAuth credentials. If you start worrying more about security, focus on how to [safely](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) store passwords.